# Dante SOCKS5 server does not send traffic through ppp interface

Tags: linux, ppp, socks5-proxy

I have a couple of 3G modems installed into my RaspberryPI via USB hub with external power adapter. The goal is to create several ppp connection via these modems and share the internet via socks5 proxy (1 carrier -> 1 dedicated port).

```
root@raspberrypi:/etc# ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.88.81  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.88.255
        inet6 fe80::be35:5f3a:e942:e39a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:92:b1:0b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 8747  bytes 702623 (686.1 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 2448  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1452  bytes 183993 (179.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 4  bytes 156 (156.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4  bytes 156 (156.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ppp-kyivstar0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.203.1.38  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 10.64.64.64
        ppp  txqueuelen 3  (Point-to-Point Protocol)
        RX packets 16  bytes 382 (382.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 16  bytes 514 (514.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ppp-vodafone0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1440
        inet 100.87.250.240  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 10.64.64.65
        ppp  txqueuelen 3  (Point-to-Point Protocol)
        RX packets 7  bytes 58 (58.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 7  bytes 82 (82.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

The config file of dante-server looks like this:

```
root@raspberrypi:/etc# grep -v "^#" /etc/danted-vodafone0.conf | grep -v "^$"
debug: 0
logoutput: stderr stdout
internal: 192.168.88.81 port = 50002
internal: 127.0.0.1 port = 50002
external: ppp-vodafone0
socksmethod: none
clientmethod: none
user.privileged: proxy
user.unprivileged: nobody
user.libwrap: nobody
client pass {
    from: 192.168.88.0/24 port 1-65535 to: 0.0.0.0/0
}
client pass {
    from: 127.0.0.0/8 port 1-65535 to: 0.0.0.0/0
}
client block {
    from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
    log: connect error
}
socks block {
    from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: lo
    log: connect error
}
socks pass {
    from: 192.168.88.0/24 to: 0.0.0.0/0
    protocol: tcp udp
}
socks pass {
    from: 127.0.0.0/8 to: 0.0.0.0/0
    protocol: tcp udp
}
socks block {
    from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
    log: connect error
}
```

When I try to test that with curl - nothing happens:

```
# curl -v --socks5 192.168.88.81:50002 http://ifconfig.co
* Rebuilt URL to: http://ifconfig.co/
*   Trying 192.168.88.81...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* SOCKS5 communication to ifconfig.co:80
* SOCKS5 connect to IPv4 104.27.140.78 (locally resolved)
* Can't complete SOCKS5 connection to 0.0.0.0:0. (6)
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Can't complete SOCKS5 connection to 0.0.0.0:0. (6)
```

From other side curl is able to make a connection through that interface when I soecify that as a parameter:

```
# curl -v --interface ppp-vodafone0 http://ifconfig.co
* Rebuilt URL to: http://ifconfig.co/
*   Trying 104.27.140.78...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Local Interface ppp-vodafone0 is ip 100.120.201.176 using address family 2
* Local port: 0
* Connected to ifconfig.co (104.27.140.78) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: ifconfig.co
> User-Agent: curl/7.52.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Sat, 08 Sep 2018 00:20:50 GMT
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 14
< Connection: keep-alive
< Set-Cookie: __cfduid=df1da9ab56a621c1a8e3a1e75faac555c1536366050; expires=Sun, 08-Sep-19 00:20:50 GMT; path=/; domain=.ifconfig.co; HttpOnly
< Via: 1.1 vegur
< Server: cloudflare
< CF-RAY: 456d4066058483ee-KBP
<
46.133.227.38
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host ifconfig.co left intact
```

What can be wrong here?

Comment: see your logs. it is possible danted is being launched before the interfaces go up?

Comment: the proxy gets started after ppp is up and running. In the logs I see: 

    Sep  9 13:39:48 (1536500388.653420) danted[28316]: debug: addexternal(): ifname ppp-vodafone0 resolved to address IPv4 address 100.92.253.239.  enabled
    Sep  9 13:39:48 (1536500388.653420) danted[28316]: debug: addexternal(): ifname ppp-vodafone0 resolved to address IPv4 address 100.92.253.239.  enabled

Comment: when I take exactly the same .conf file and replace `ppp-vodafone0` to `eth0` - the connection goes smoothly.

Comment: when I put the IP of the ppp-vodafone0 interface instead of interface name - the connection stucks as well :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. First of all, during ppp session I especially set up the ppp peer *without* default route provisioning. Because of this the outgoing packet from pppX interface had no idea how to be routed. The situation was resolved with so called policy based routing.

First of all you need to pre-define all your additional routing tables in `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables`. My files looks like this:

```
# Ansible managed
#
# reserved values
#
255 local
254 main
253 default
0   unspec
#
# local
#
#1  inr.ruhep
103 kyivstar0
101 lifecell0
102 vodafone0
```

These 101..103 are the routing tables for PPP interfaces. After that you need to set up the policy. It looks like this:

```
ip rule add from 100.83.31.204 table vodafone0
ip route add 0.0.0.0/0 via 10.64.64.64 dev ppp-vodafone0 table vodafone0
```

Where:

- `100.83.31.204` - Local PPP IP address
- `10.64.64.64` - Remote PPP IP address
- `ppp-vodafone0` - the name of PPP interface
- `vodafone0` - the route table name predefined in `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables`

After tuning up policy based routing everything works as expected.